# Full screen view in LibreOffice?

Tags: fullscreen, libreoffice-writer

Is there a way to view and edit documents in LibreOffice Writer in fullscreen? Preferably, I would like to view two pages side by side, but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> toggles Fullscreen mode, more info here: [LibreOffice Help - Full Screen](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Full_Screen)

Comment: And Command + Shift + J if you're a mac user.

Comment: Though it is not written in the help page, LibreDraw doesn't work or has not the fullscreen feature. https://superuser.com/questions/1126310/full-screen-view-in-libreoffice-draw

Answer (score 5):

On menu, go to `View > Zoom > Zoom...`. There, on `View layout`, choose `Columns` and put there how many pages side by side you want.

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to Fullscreen (or from the menu `View > Fullscreen`; <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit).

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Wheel mouse up/down to adjust the page size as you want (or before going to Fullscreen, set menu `View > Zoom` to adjust in "width and height" or as you want).

Comment: I think the `View > Zoom > Choose columns` option is no longer available, certainly not showing in LibreOffice 4.0.0.3.

Comment: You edited the answer on a way it would not point to correct location. I reedited it.

Comment: Please, consider my LibreOffice is in Portuguese, so I can miss some translation.

Answer (score 0):

Go into View on the menu bar and click the entry for Full Screen, second one from the bottom.

Comment: If it is in fullscreen mode, you can't go into the view menu. It can work only if you want to go to fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 0):

**IF** the question is to have the office app open in a full screen window VS a smaller window on the desktop...
Then size the APP picker window (that opens when you click on the Libre Office Icon) to the preferred size, or maximize it, BEFORE you open a APP. The APP then opens in the same size window and will be remembered next time.