# Full screen view in LibreOffice Draw?

Tags: libreoffice, fullscreen, libreoffice-draw

I'm not seeing an option to view in fullscreen in LibreOffice draw, even after checking the "view" tab.  Am I missing something or is basic fullscreen functionality not included in LibreOffice Draw?  If so, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look as if fullscreen function is available for Draw (thought it DOES appear in Writer and Calc).

There's at least one outstanding feature request:

https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51566&redirected_from=fdo